# Computed properties with v-model by index

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Let's say I have the following vuex store...

```
state: {
  someObj: { 
    someList: [
      { key:'a', someSubList: [] },
      { key:'b', someSubList: [] },
      { key:'c', someSubList: [] },
    ]
  }
}
```

How would I bind a separate v-model to each someSubList? As an example, after I check some checkboxes, I would expect to see some Ids be populated into the someSubList like this:

```
    someList: [
      { key:'a', someSubList: [1, 13, 17, 19] },
      { key:'b', someSubList: [1, 2, 3, 4] },
      { key:'c', someSubList: [4, 16, 20] },
    ]
```

In other words, If I check a checkbox an associated id would be added to someSubList. If I uncheck the box, the id associated with that checkbox would be removed from the someSubList. Keep in mind that each someList has a different someSubList.

I'm thinking it would be similar to below, but I'm not sure what to use for the v-model param and how to pass the index to the set method

ex.

```
<span v-for="(someListRow.someSubList, index2) in someList" v-bind:key="index2">
  <v-checkbox v-model="myModel" />
</span>

computed: {
 someList: {
    get() {
      return this.$store.state.someObj.someList;
    }, 
    set(value) {
      this.$store.commit('someCommit', value)
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

For anyone interested I got it solved using the tips provided in the posts below and ended up doing this:

```
<v-checkbox @change="myChangeMethod($event, myObj)" label="MyLabel" 
 :input-value="isMyObjSelected(myObj)" />

myChangeMethod(event, myObj) {
  if (event) {
    this.$store.commit('AddToMyList', {myObj});
  } else {
    this.$store.commit('RemoveFromMyList', {myObj});
  }
}
isMyObjSelected(myObj){
    this.$store.getters.isMyObjSelected(myObj});
}
```

Comment: sorry was a typo. I edited it

Comment: u want ? `<v-checkbox v-model="myModel" :value="someSubList" />`

Comment: I am interested in how to bind v-model. In this case how to map the "myModel" param. The value (I believe) is irrelevant to this question

Comment: Could you extend the example data to include some entries inside`someSubList`? There are several different ways to interpret this question depending on how you expect the checkboxes to relate to that array. Is your question specific to checkboxes or is it a more general question for any type of input? The boolean nature of checkbox values makes them a special case so the answer is not necessarily the same as it would be for inputs more generally.

Comment: Hi skirtle. I edited the question to help in understanding what I'm thinking of doing

Comment: use `@change="change($event, index, list, 'constant-param')"` event - as you have an undefined set of checkboxes that can add .... otherwise its this you are using: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/3a9fdc292af97c98be91c014bde1fac40a96e865/packages/vuetify/src/mixins/selectable/index.ts#L26

Comment: I think I understand. Thanks!

Comment: It seems to work, but now I cannot programmatically set the checkbox to true w/o the v-model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to map your inputs to some value in your store?
For this to work you cannot use v-model. Instead work with a `input="updateStore($event, 'pathToStoreField')"`  (or `@change="..."`) listener and a `:value="..."` binding. In case of a checkbox you need to use `:checked="..."` instead of `value`.

For example:

```
<input type="checkbox" :checked="isChecked" @input="updateField($event.target.checked, 'form.field')">

...
computed:
...
  isChecked() {
    return this.$store.state.form.field;
  },
...
methods: {
  ...
  updateField(value, path) {
    const options = { path, value };
    this.$store.commit('setFieldByPath', options);
  },
  ...
},
```

Then in your store you will need a mutation `setFieldByPath` that resolves the string-path to a property in the state object (`state.form.field`) and sets this property to `value`.

You can also place the `updateField()` method as `setter` of a computer property.

There is library that makes this a bit more convenient: https://github.com/maoberlehner/vuex-map-fields

Just look out for checkboxes: to set them checked the `checked` property needs to be `true` not the `value` property.

Comment: Thanks for the tips!  However, it seems that v-checkbox doesn't support the checked property. It only works on the input type=checkbox.

Comment: Ok, I've got it working now. Update is posted in the OP

Answer (score 0):

I think, unsure but Computed values usually become like a local variable available, you need to `v-model` what other variable is being posted through form, so if `myModel` is the variable passed through then set the value of the setter once received:

```
<span v-for="(myList, index2) in someList" v-bind:key="index2">
  <v-checkbox v-model="myModel" />
</span>
```

Then in script

```
computed: {
 myList() {
      return this.$store.state.someObj.someList;
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following. In the code sample you provided it has myModel in the checkbox but no reference to it in the computed

Comment: myModel would be the variable name inside data as per above that you would then pick up when posted. It might be a sub component of an item in data  `data() {
  return {
    myObject:{myModel: ''}
  }
},` where then you would  `v-model:myObject.myModel` its down to what or how things being picked up I guess when sent

Answer (score 0):

I guess u ask for this:

```js
<span v-for="(someSubList, index2) in someList" v-bind:key="index2">
  <v-checkbox v-model="myModel" />
</span>

data() {
  return {
    myModel: ''
  }
},
computed: {
 someList: {
    get() {
      return this.$store.state.someObj.someList;
    }, 
    set(value) {
      this.$store.commit('someCommit', value)
    }
  }
}
```

properties inside `data()` can be used to bind your v-model's on your template.

Comment: No, that has myModel in the data section. I want it to be bound directly to the someSubList within the correct someList

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested I got it solved using the tips provided in the posts below and ended up doing this:

```
<v-checkbox @change="myChangeMethod($event, myObj)" label="MyLabel" 
 :input-value="isMyObjSelected(myObj)" />

myChangeMethod(event, myObj) {
  if (event) {
    this.$store.commit('AddToMyList', {myObj});
  } else {
    this.$store.commit('RemoveFromMyList', {myObj});
  }
}
isMyObjSelected(myObj){
    this.$store.getters.isMyObjSelected(myObj});
}
```